# Rails geocoder gem find city

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am trying to find the city of the user, now I can see the address method working fine in my controller

```
def your_location
  Geocoder.address(request.remote_ip)
end
```

But I can't figure out how to find the user city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Geocoder GitHub](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#request-geocoding-by-ip-address):

> Geocoder adds `location` and `safe_location` methods to the standard
>   **Rack::Request** object so you can easily look up the location of any
>   HTTP request by IP address. For example, in a Rails controller or a
>   Sinatra app:

```
# returns Geocoder::Result object
result = request.location
```

`location` hash example:

```
{
  "data"=>{
    "ip"=>"213.174.0.254",
    "city"=>"Lviv",
    "latitude"=>49.8383,
    "zip_code"=>"79000",
    "longitude"=>24.0232,
    "time_zone"=>"Europe/Kiev",
    "metro_code"=>0,
    "region_code"=>"46",
    "region_name"=>"L'vivs'ka Oblast'",
    "country_code"=>"UA",
    "country_name"=>"Ukraine"
  },
  "cache_hit"=>nil
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed it. Thank you so much! that did the job :)